# I want to connect two databases using single cfg.xml file in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

I want to connect two databases using single cfg.xml file in hibernate. How to connect multiple database using only one cfg.xml in Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Define two session factories. Each session factory will have connection detail specific to one database.

Comment: Thanks Jitesh , Please can you elaborate your answer ....  Acutally I dont know how to use two session factory in one cfg.xml file .

Comment: If you want hibernate only solution, then you cannot define two session factories in hibernate configuration file. You will have to have two hibernate configuration files to connect to two databases.But if you are working with spring and hibernate , you can define two different session factory beans connecting to two different data sources.